# Any best idea to do this? Codeigniter 4, how to make: no request on View, only on Controller?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-4

Here is my Controller:

```
$data = [
  'mainMenu' => $this->mainmenuModel->getAll(),
  'subMenu' => $this->submenuModel->getAll()
];
return view('dashboard/user', $data);
```

Here is my View:

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="nav-brand">My Web Admin</a>
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul>
            <?php foreach($mainMenu as $dtmainmenu): ?>
              <li>
                <a href="#"><?=$dtmainmenu['menu_name']; ?></a>
                <ul>
                  <?php $idmainmenu = $dtmainmenu['id_mainmenu'] ?>
                  <?php $db = \Config\Database::connect(); ?> // AVOID DOING THIS ON VIEW
                  <?php $submenu = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE id_mainmenu = $idmainmenu"); ?> // AVOID DOING THIS ON VIEW
                  <?php foreach($submenu as $dtsubmenu): ?>
                    <li><a href="#"><?=$dtsubmenu['submenu_name']; ?></a></li>
                  <?php endForeach; ?>
                </ul>
              </li>
            <?php endForeach; ?>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tables Example is below:

Main Menu

| id_mainmenu | menu_name | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Home | Kontent |
| 2 | About Us | Kontent |
| 3 | News | Kontent |
| 4 | Travel | Kontent |
| 5 | Contact | Kontent |

Sub Menu

| id_submenu | id_mainmenu | submenu_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Local News |
| 2 | 3 | Sport News |
| 3 | 4 | Adventures |
| 4 | 4 | Must Visits |
| 5 | 4 | Local Attrac |

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a core library that handles data. Fetch all data to single arrray, than use it in your view properly.